# What is Membership Provider on MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Asp.Net MVC 4 Internet Application uses SimpleMembership. When you create a new MVC project on Visual Studio 2013 Preview, I think MVC 5 uses the new one. Do you know anything about it??

SimpleMembership;

[image]

A membership which I don't know the name for MVC 5;

[image]

Comment: It seems, to me, the same as MVC 4 SimpleMembership tables. Also I don't see nothing new on this argument in the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes) of the new version.

Comment: I changed my question.. You can see SimpleMembership tables. I think all tables are different..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was looking for this in files and I found IdentityConfig.cs file..

It is ASP.NET Identity and ASP.NET Identity is the new membership system for building ASP.NET web applications. ASP.NET Identity allows you to add login features to your application and makes it easy to customize data about the logged in user.

// For more information on ASP.NET Identity, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301863

Comment: Wish it was easy to use the old Membership system. It was easy to set up and worked fine. No need to figure out how to use new systems. Complete waste of time.

Comment: I've been playing with it for a few hours.  It's actually pretty cool, but almost impossible to use in a Database-First setup.  Definitely needs some updates soon.

Comment: @Lé Muffin Man `Web.config` <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />